# Check hash validity

Tags: php, yii, hash, yii2

I'm trying to validate password against invalid hash stored in database. Instead of getting `false` (as I supposed) in this situation, my application dies with `Invalid hash` exception.

Is there any Yii2-built-in way to validate hash, before feeding it to `validatePassword`, to handle this kind of situation more gently?

Or the only way I'm left with is to copy code used by `validatePassword`:

```
if (!preg_match('/^\$2[axy]\$(\d\d)\$[\.\/0-9A-Za-z]{22}/', $hash, $matches) || $matches[1] < 4 || $matches[1] > 30) {
    throw new InvalidParamException('Hash is invalid.');
}
```

to my own code and simply not call `validatePassword`, when hash is invalid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use `try` - `catch` block in your password validation:

```
/**
 * Validates password
 *
 * @param  string $password password to validate
 * @return boolean if password provided is valid for current user
 */
public function validatePassword($password)
{
    try {
        $data = Yii::$app->getSecurity()->validatePassword($password, $this->password_hash);
        return $data;
    } catch(\yii\base\InvalidParamException $e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Something like that, but why you even want to try to validate hash if it's already malformed? Maybe some criminal will pass something bad there, which can pass your login etc.

Comment: Nice, I simply forgot about `try... catch`! :> I'm trying this code in down migration, to reverse, what I have done in up migration. In up migration I'm searching user tables for all users, that have empty password. For any of such, I'm generating password by hashing his/her e-mail. I know, that this is stupid, but this is only for an internal and temporal solution, and will never be made public, so should fit in. In down migration I have to reverse this operation, so I need to know if password stored in DB is a hash of user e-mail. If so, I want to reset it to an empty string.

Comment: I haven't figured out any better way for checking if `password` field contains hashed `email` other than actually using `validatePassword($this->email, $this->password)`. So, if an malformed hash pops in, then I have to catch that, because that means, that user password is _something else_, it was not _generated_ in up migration and therefore shouldn't be reversed to empty string in down migration. Again, I know, how stupid this sounds, but fortunately, this is only an internal and short living solution.